# SQL Server -- updating the `sys.*` tables and not just reading them

Tags: sql, sql-server

In an attempt to the query

```
UPDATE sys.columns 
SET user_type_id = 106
WHERE object_id in (select object_id from sys.objects where type = 'U') and user_type_id = 108
```

I'm getting the error:

> Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

Is there a way to get around this? In this case, I'm looking to change the types of all decimal fields of all the tables in the database.

Can do this "externally"-- without direct tampering with `sys.*` tables (haven't yet pinned down how-to though), but I'm looking to know whether I can update the `sys.*` tables -- and if so, which ones, when/how?

// =========================

**EDIT:**

would i be able to get any "deeper" than `alter table...` if i had full privileges for db access? 
not sure what kind of privileges i have now, but would look into it.

Comment: direct updates to the system tables are not supported starting with SQL Server 2005 and it wouldn't be really safe anyway, @siride suggestion is a better approach

Comment: To answer your edit: no. `ALTER TABLE` is the proper way to change your table schema.

Comment: This is like starting your car engine by lighting a match and holding it inside the fuel injector - you could probably get it going, but it'd be dangerous, and much more difficult than using the standard `ALTER TABLE` commands.

Comment: Those are **system views** (not tables) and you **cannot** update them yourself - those are under the SQL Server's control only...

Comment: @Dave.Gugg -  getting into a car engine w/a burning match has some use sometimes-- dont hve to burn it all around. the DB engine giving access to some things-- like altering varchar(50) to varchar(70) directly on sys.columns wouldn't harm anything around. but then too costly to do the bits n infeasible infeasible i gather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tables are informational only. I want to make this clear: the `sys.*` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.*` views exist to provide schema information from the database engine in a useful format. They do not represent the actual schema of the database*, and modifying them is thus impossible. The *only* way to change your schema is to use DDL (Data Definition Language) statements, such as `ALTER TABLE`.

In your case, you can use a cursor to iterate through all columns with the wrong type, generate SQL statements to correct that, and execute them dynamically. Here's a skeleton of how that would look:

```
DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR
 SELECT schemas.name AS schema_name,
        objects.name AS table_name,
        columns.name AS column_name
   FROM sys.columns
   JOIN sys.objects
     ON objects.object_id = columns.object_id
   JOIN sys.schemas
     ON schemas.schema_id = objects.schema_id
  WHERE objects.type = 'U'
    AND columns.user_type_id = 108

DECLARE @schema_name VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @column_name VARCHAR(255)

OPEN column_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name, @column_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

    -- TODO: modify to change to the actual type, scale and precision you want; also you may need to adjust for NOT NULL constraints, default constraints and foreign keys (all exercises for the reader)
    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ' CHANGE COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(@column_name) + ' DECIMAL(12, 2)'
    EXEC(@sql)  

    FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name, @column_name
END

CLOSE column_cursor
DEALLOCATE column_cursor
```

Because of the potential increase in complexity for dealing with constraints and keys, I'd recommend either updating the columns manually, building the `ALTER TABLE` statements manually, dumping your schema to script, updating that and recreating the tables and objects, or looking for a 3rd party tool that does this kind of thing (I don't know of any).

*For the `sys.*` views, at least, it's possible that they closely represent the underlying data structures, though I think there's still some abstraction. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is ANSI-defined, so it is unlikely to match the internal structures of any database system out there.

Comment: so - no other alternative than "alter table"(?) tempering with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.*` things didn't work either.

Comment: @user4402742, `ALTER TABLE` is the correct, accepted way to alter your tables in SQL databases.

Comment: @user4402742: I edited to make it very clear that the `sys.*` views are read-only and only for information. They do not represent the actual internal data structures of the DB engine.

Comment: @siride - Isn't there a way to use an inner query to get the list of what to alter-- something like 

**"ALTER TABLE <anAlias> in (select name from sys.tables where object_id ...) 
ALTER COLUMN <column_alias> in (... )"**

Comment: @user4402742: DDL statements aren't composable like that.

Comment: @user4402742: it might be a good idea to read the docs on `ALTER TABLE`. They will answer the rest of your questions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(v=sql.105).aspx